# What is the reason for the / in M/≈

Tags: elementary-set-theory, automata

So you have a non minimal DFA $M$ and you create a minimal DFA $M_{/≈}$. What is the meaning of $M_{/≈}$? I understand that the $≈$ tells that this $M_{/≈}$ is the equivalent version of the original $M$ but I see no specific reason to use $/$ instead of something akin to $M`_≈$

And if there is a reason, what is the name of the $M_{/≈}$ notation so I can look further into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on a set $S$, then the “quotient set” $S/{\sim}$ is the set of equivalence classes ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class)).

In your case, it's $M/{\approx}$ (not $M_{/{\approx}}$), the set of equivalence classes under the relation $\approx$ on $M$. It's unclear what you mean by “the equivalent version of the original $M$”, but that seems to be a misinterpretation.

Comment: “the equivalent version of the original M” is me expressing the fact that a DFA minimized using Myhill–Nerode is equivalent in behaviour but not in states. And now I get that M/≈ is the application of the relation on M and as such results in a different minimal DFA.